# Как в sql преобразовать строку в вещественное число?

Tags: firebird, sql

Как в sql преобразовать строку в вещественное число?

Comment: Внимание - в SQL! СУБД - firebird 2.0 - 2.5 Желательно - код процедуры. Необходимо для использования в запросах (конструкция select)

Answer (score 1):

```
    set term ^;
    create or alter procedure str2dbl(str varchar(20))
    returns (dbl double precision) as
    begin
      dbl=null;
      begin
        begin
          dbl=cast(str as double precision);
        end
        when any do begin end
      end
      suspend;
    end
    ^set term ;^
    commit;
    -----------------
    -- Test:
    C:\1INSTALL\FIREBIRD\Data>isql -n TESTX.fdb
    Database:  TESTX.fdb
SQL> select * from str2dbl('111.23')
CON> union all
CON> select * from str2dbl('11152.')
CON> union all
CON> select * from str2dbl('.88819')
CON> union all
CON> select * from str2dbl('44,333')
CON> union all
CON> select * from str2dbl('......')
CON> union all
CON> select * from str2dbl('йцукенг');

                    DBL
=======================
      111.2300000000000
      11152.00000000000
     0.8881900000000000
                 <null>
                 <null>
                 <null>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте стандартную конструкцию, например:

> select cast('12.35' as dec(6,2))

Comment: Не сработает - у Вас же самого написана строка через точку в коде. На ней и споткнется.

Comment: Собственно, результат: 
Arithmetic overflow or division by zero has occurred.
arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation.
Cannot transliterate character between character sets.

Comment: Если это проблема языковых настроек, то значит будет работать с запятой. Или явно используйте соответствующий COLLATE.